# JPA findAll throws EntityNotFoundException instead of empty list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot project which consists of an entity with one to many relationships as below however when I use `roleForecastingRepository.findAll()` method it do return **javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.integrella.zoho.domain.Opportunity with id ABC132** instead of an empty list or list of records of role-forecasting.

**RoleForecasting.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(exclude = "opportunity")
@Entity
@Table(name = "RoleForecasting")
public class RoleForecasting extends AbstractAuditingEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "`Id`")
  @Schema(example = "1")
  private Long id;

  ...

  @ManyToOne
  @JsonIgnore
  private Opportunity opportunity;

}
```

**Opportunity.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "Opportunity")
public class Opportunity extends AbstractAuditingEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "`Id`")
  private String id;

  ...

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "opportunity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<RoleForecasting> roleForecastings;

}
```

**RoleForecastingRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface RoleForecastingRepository extends JpaRepository<RoleForecasting, Long> {

}
```

**UPDATE:**

Please note that Opportunity with id ABC132 do present in the Opportunity table and and RoleForecasting table also has correct FK i.e ABC132

Comment: Based on the error message not `RoleForecasting` entity is affected. The related `Opportunity` entity is missing by id ABC132

Answer (score 0):

A given identifier cannot be found in the persistence context or database. In your case, it seems that the Opportunity entity with the identifier "ABC132" is not present in the database, but there exists a RoleForecasting entity that has a foreign key relationship with this missing Opportunity entity.

To resolve this issue, you can ensure that the Opportunity entity with the identifier "ABC132" exists in the database before fetching the related RoleForecasting entities. You can do this by querying the OpportunityRepository for the Opportunity entity with the given identifier. Or, you can update the RoleForecasting entity to use a nullable foreign key relationship with the Opportunity entity. This will allow the RoleForecasting entity to exist in the database even if the related Opportunity entity is missing. You can update the RoleForecasting entity

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "opportunity_id", nullable = true)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Opportunity opportunity;
```

With this change, the RoleForecasting entity will still have a foreign key relationship with the Opportunity entity if it exists, but it will not throw an EntityNotFoundException if the Opportunity entity is missing.

Comment: Opportunity with id ABC132 do present in the Opportunity table and and RoleForecasting table also has correct FK i.e ABC132